# haskell, sieve a list with multiple filters

Tags: list, haskell, filter

Given the type

```
sieve :: [a -> Bool] -> [a] -> [[a]]
```

I have to write a function, which filters a list using a list of functions `[a->Bool]`.
Each filter must only sieve through what the filters before left over.
It gives back a list of lists, each list representing what was caught by the sieve.
The last list is what has not been caught by any of the filters.
e.g.

```
sieve [(<3),(>7),odd] [1..10] gives back [[1,2],[8,9,10],[3,5,7],[4,6]]
```

I know sieve must start this way...

```
sieve fs xs = concat $ filter () ...
```

My problem is:
Before I can go to the complicated part of the work, the step by step filtering, I don't get how to access each of the functions in the function list and use it on the [a] list.
If it was one function it would be easy with `(filter f xs)`

I tried a lot and don't get it.

Can someone please help and possibly give a little hint how to manage the one after another filter system?
Any hint is welcome.

EDIT:

I now have this: 
It is the way I think it should work but I have a problem negating the boolean function...
Can you help?

```
    sieve :: [a -> Bool] -> [a] -> [[a]]
    sieve [] xs = [xs]
    sieve (f:fs) xs = (filter f xs) : (sieve fs (filter nf xs))

            where nf = not f
```

This does not work because I may not use (not f) like this.
Any idea?

EDIT: FINAL SOLUTION

partition p xs = (filter p xs, filter (not . p) xs)

```
    sieve :: [a -> Bool] -> [a] -> [[a]]
    sieve [] xs = [xs];
    sieve (f:fs) xs = p1 : (sieve fs p2)
    where p1 = fst (partition f xs)
          p2 = snd (partition f xs)
```

Comment: Why don't you use a recursive function: run the first filter, then recursively call the function with the resulting list and the rest of the functions. You'll also have to accumulate the results...

Comment: `filter` alone won't get the job done. You need both what is removed from the list, and what is left over. In fact, the resulting list is a partition of the input list.  *cough, cough*

Comment: Yeah,
filter is not enough;
Recursive is the right idea, I think and concat was the wrong idea, too

Comment: I managed to combine a few functions from `Data.List` to implement this without any manual recursion. I don't know if using the full power of `Data.List` is within the scope of your assignment, but it's certainly possible you could get inspiration from something in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do something for each element of a list and accumulate the results when you do that, this is exactly what fold functions are for:

```
import Data.List (partition, foldl')

sieve fs xs = let (p1, p2) = fold fs xs in p2 ++ [p1]
    where fold fs xs = foldl' step (xs, []) fs
          step (lst, rs) f = let (r1, r2) = partition f lst in (r2, rs++[r1])
```

To implement it by using recursion, what you need to do is filtering the list left behind by the filter before it, and collect results when you do this:

```
import Data.List (partition)

sieve [] xs = [xs]
sieve (f:fs) xs = let (p1, p2) = partition f xs
                   in p1 : sieve fs p2
```

Comment: Your use of the partition made it clear to me. Thanks.
I implemented it differently.
I edit my original post an add my implementation

Comment: @user3556115 `partition` is a function offered by `Data.List`, you do not have to implement it by yourself.

Comment: @user3556115 You need to import `Data.List` first, add `import Data.List` at the beginning of your source file.